# Why is last channel's expiry different in Lightning Network Routes?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-routing, lightning-rfc

Both in the Basic of Lightning Technology ([BOLT](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc)) documents, and in the specification of lnd, there is a different treatment for the last channel in a route. In [BOLT#2](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md) it refers to a variable `min_final_cltv_expiry`:

> `min_final_cltv_expiry` is the minimum difference between HTLC CLTV timeout and the current
>   block height, for the terminal case (C).

This value is 9, as opposed to 144 for `cltv_expiry_delta`.

This is most likely related with the output of a route when querying lnd, for example, suppose the route Alice -> Bob -> Carol -> Dave, routed from Alice:
the output is:

```
$> lncli-alice queryroutes --dest=<Carol_pubkey> --amt=5 --num_max_routes=1
total_time_lock: 1443640
total_fees: 1
total_amt: 6
hops {
  chan_id: <id_chan_alice_bob>
  chan_capacity: <cap>
  amt_to_forward: 6
  expiry: 1443610
  amt_to_forward_msat: 6000
  fee_msat: 1
}
hops {
  chan_id: <id_chan_bob_carol>
  chan_capacity: <cap>
  amt_to_forward: 5
  fee: 1
  expiry: 1443466
  amt_to_forward_msat: 5000
  fee_msat: 1000
}
hops {
  chan_id: <id_chan_carol_dave>
  chan_capacity: <cap>
  amt_to_forward: 5
  expiry: 1443466
  amt_to_forward_msat: 5000
}
total_fees_msat: 1001
total_amt_msat: 6001
```

Notice the last two hops have the same `expiry` value. Why is the last hop different with regard to the expiry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some searching through the [BOLT](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/07-routing-gossip.md) documents and talking with the lnd [slack](https://lightningcommunity.slack.com/) community, I found an answer:

> B->C. If B were to send 4,999,999 millisatoshi directly to C, it would
>   neither charge itself a fee nor add its own cltv_expiry_delta, so it
>   would use C's requested min_final_cltv_expiry of 9. Presumably it
>   would also add a shadow route to give an extra CLTV of 42.
>   Additionally, it could add extra CLTV deltas at other hops, as these
>   values represent a minimum, but chooses not to do so here, for the
>   sake of simplicity:

Also, although `cltv_expiry_delta` is default to 9 in BOLT, in `lnd` they use 144, but without checking for the final hop. That is, they do not add the `final_cltv_expiry` because they have already a big `cltv_expiry` (I presume). Olaoluwa said in the slack 
that they plan to reduce the value of `cltv_expiry_delta` to get closer to the default value listed in BOLT. However, if they do this, I hope they take care of adding the additional `cltv_expiry_delta`, as it will be important to add in this case. For an example of what I mean, check the above-linked link for BOLT #007